# Keyword Arguments in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2, keyword-argument

So I am trying to read data from a Wikipedia page using urllib2/BeautifulSoup. I copied this code into terminal:

```
import urllib2

hdrs = { 'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11" } 
req = urllib2.Request("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_mobile_phone_companies" , headers = hdrs)
fd = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

It works fine. However, when I make this call (removing the keyword argument) instead:

```
req = urllib2.Request("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_mobile_phone_companies" , hdrs)
```

I get an error:

```
 TypeError: must be string or buffer, not dict
```

Why does this happen? I thought keyword arguments were optional in a function call. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

The second parameter for [urllib2.Request](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) is data, not header.

```
class urllib2.Request(url[, data][, headers][, origin_req_host][, unverifiable])
```

To specify headers without specifying data, you should use keyword argument form.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't so sure on how to interpret the documentation. What exactly does [, parameter] mean (i.e. why is is in this list-like format)?

Comment: @MEric `[, parameter]` means: `parameter` is optional.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

```
urllib2.Request(url[, data][, headers][, origin_req_host][, unverifiable])
```

You can do this:

```
req = urllib2.Request("<url>", None, hdrs)
```

Comment: Only if the defualt value for `data` is indeed `None` (which indeed is). (Just wanted to make people sensitive for this problem in general, not in this case.)

Answer (score 2):

Structure of urllib2's request function is :

```
urllib2.Request(url[, data][, headers][, origin_req_host][, unverifiable])
```

when you call your functions in python you need to either give the name of the arguments e.g. `urllib2.request(headers = hdrs, url = my_url)`

or you need to provide the arguments in the order they are given in the function definition.

So on your second function python assumes that you are giving hdrs as the value for data parameter, and thus the datatype mismatch.